# USQL msbuild - composite build output

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, u-sql

I'm following the instructions on this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/10/24/continuous-integration-made-easy-with-msbuild-support-for-u-sql-preview/

It states that

> After running MSBuild from command line or as a VSTS task, all scripts in the U-SQL project are built and output to a single file at "Build output path/script name/script name.usql". You can **copy this composite U-SQL script** to the release folder for further deployment.

Within my Visual Studio project (.usqlproj) I have multiple .usql scripts

- CreateDatabase.usql
- CreateTable.usql
- CreateTvf.usql

when I do clean and msbuild and then check bin\debug folder, all I get is just CreateDatabase.usql and within that there is only CREATE DATBASE statement. As per the blog I would have thought all the 3 usql scripts would have merged into 1 composite usql script. The msbuild command I executed from command prompt on my machine

```
msbuild TheProject\TheProject.usqlproj /t:Clean /t:Rebuild /property:USQLSDKPath=C:\TheProject\src\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime,USQLTargetType=Merge
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.4.3 and Azure Data Lake tools 2.3.0000.1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to some legacy reasons, to make sure all files in the usqlproj are built, the condition are defined in
USqlSDKBuild.targets as below
    
    `<ItemGroup>
        <FileToBuild Condition="'$(JustOneFile)' == '' and
        '$(Build_all_files_in_this_project)' != 'true'" Include="$(ActiveFile)" />
        <FileToBuild Condition="'$(JustOneFile)' != '' " Include="$(JustOneFile)" />
        <FileToBuild Condition="'$(Build_all_files_in_this_project)' == 'true'"
        Include="Build_all_files_in_this_project" />
    </ItemGroup>`

For current preview release, please add "/property:Build_all_files_in_this_project=true,JustOneFile=''" to the command line to make sure all scripts are built.  We will update this in later releases with a easier and simpler condition.

Answer (score 0):

The command msbuild `TheProject\TheProject.usqlproj /t:Clean /t:Rebuild /property:USQLSDKPath=C:\TheProject\src\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime,USQLTargetType=Merge` actually build the script you selected.

If you are selecting `CreateDatabase.usql` in VS, it will build the script `CreateDatabase.usql` in command line.

As below example, since it's selecting `test.usql`, when execute msbuild command, it will only build `test.usql`. As the way clicking **Build** button for the USQL project.

[image]

If you want to **build all the scripts under the USQL project**, you should select **Build All Scripts** button in VS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Yes, right click Build All Scripts will Build_all_files_in_this_project. How do we get the same behaviour in **msbuild command line**?

2) That's still not producing **a single composite U-SQL script** - which I can use in release and further deployment - as mentioned in the blog. It is actually producing 3 different .usql scripts in bin\Debug folder. Or did I misunderstood the blog?

Comment: The article also says "output to **a single file** at "Build output path/script name/script name.usql"". In order to understanding it correctly, I added a comment under the article, you can follow up.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding of "Merge" target here. The "Merge" target is not to merge all U-SQL scripts in current directory into a single larger script.  Instead, it is to "compiles code-behind files, like .cs, and inlines the resulting user defined code library into the U-SQL script."   So, if you have 3 U-SQL scripts in project, the merged compile result will be 3 different files in 3 target folders.